# Rails + Prawn_rails: How do I add an image to my PDF?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf

I'm using this gem to use Prawn to create a PDF: https://github.com/Whoops/prawn-rails

However, I can't seem to figure out how to add an image. I've tried `pdf.image "path/to/img.jpg` but it would say the file is not a recognized format.

I've also looked into this on page 101: http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/manual.pdf , but it doesn't work.

This is happening in the views:

```
    prawn_document() do |pdf|
        pdf.image "#{Rails.root}/public/logo.gif"

    end
```

This throws:

```
Prawn::Errors::UnsupportedImageType at /admin/purchases/6188.pdf

image file is an unrecognised format
```

Same happens for a .jpg image

Comment: What is the exact error?  Have you tried another image?

Comment: Yeh I tried to type gibberish `pdf.image "nonexisting/image/path.jpg"` and it said it couldn't find the image (which was good), but then I passed it the path of a real image and it didn't work. Unrecognized format

Comment: But did you actually try a different .jpg file?

Comment: Prawn supports PNG and JPG images, so .GIFs won't work.

Comment: @eugen you were right, I needed a JPG image.

Comment: I had been using similar Rails convention with `Rails.root.join('...')` to generate my pathname, ends up I needed to add `.to_s` when using it to get it to work, ex: `pdf.image Rails.root.join('...').to_s`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this.

```
gem 'prawn'

bundle install
```

In your controller.

```
      def controller_method
         pdf = Prawn::Document.new
         begin
            pdf_file_path = "#{Rails.root}/public/output"
            full_doc = "#{Rails.root}/public/something.png" 
            pdf.image full_doc
            pdf.start_new_page
            pdf.render_file pdf_file_path
         rescue Prawn::Errors::UnsupportedImageType
             flash[:notice] = "Image unsupported"
             redirect_to '/handle'
         end
      end
```

Comment: Is this possible in the views? I updated my question to be more specific

Answer (score 0):

Adding an image is easy enough.

```
def download
  @document = Document.find(params[:id])
  tmp_file = Tempfile.new(Digest::MD5.hexdigest(rand(12).to_s))
  pdf = Prawn::Document.generate(tmp_file.path, :margin => 0, :page_size => "A4", :skip_page_creation => true) do |posting|
    posting.start_new_page
    posting.image @document.user.logo.path
    send_data posting.render, :filename => "whatever.pdf", :type => "application/pdf"
  end
end
```

Obviously `@document.user.logo.path` could be a literal path, that's just a Paperclip attachment in this case.

**UPDATE**

If it's a literal path you might need to do something like this:

```
require "open-uri"

def download
  ...
  posting.image File.open("/path/to/image.jpg")
  ...
end
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, I'm running into this issue in the view. I'll update the question

Comment: I've updated my answer with something that might help, but note that the code you mentioned was in your view really shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the latest prawn (version 1.0.0) has changed.  You'll get

```
undefined method `image=' for #<Prawn::Document
```

if you try and apply something to pdf.image.

This worked for me:

```
img = "#{Rails.root}/public/my_lovely_image.png" 

Prawn::Document.new(background: img)
```